# Problem opening UE4 project (uassets not importing)

Tags: git, unreal-engine4

recently I setup my project with git using sourcetree because I was switching computers. I just put my entire project in the repo folder and uploaded it to github (using LFS). I didn't have any problems with that, but trying to open it up on my other computer keeps giving me this error:

```
 Failed to load map!
 ../../../../../../Users/coopb/Desktop/physics-dev/sandbox/Content/FirstPersonBP/Maps/MainMenuLevel.umap appears to be an asset file.
```

Everything should be .uasset right? The project loads fine, all folders are in the correct place, plugins loaded fine. How could I fix this. it's really bugging me!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same Issue. Some googling told me that the file is probably corrupted but in my effort to get the Map working again, I extracted it from a build that I know is working.

As far as I can tell, theres no known way to fix it besides making sure your files were not corrupted by the transfer.